# How to evaluate √|x| ? Since this function is even f(x)=f(-x), but root is not defined for negative values.

Tags: functions, roots, absolute-value

I have been trying to figure out how √-x is plotted in the graph, as root is only defined for positive real values.

Comment: You cannot plot this on a graph representing only real values.

Comment: You already know that $f(x) = f(-x)$; therefore the graph on the negative values is the **mirror image** of that on the positive values of $x$.

Comment: @masiewpao I know that we can plot the graph for real values but it seems like you skipped the body of the question.

Comment: @MattiP. I thought the same way but still un-convinced as root is defined for real values and whenever we say √-3 we make it as i√3 ( i is the imaginary part)

Comment: Yes but you don't have to calculate $\sqrt{-3}$ ! When you plug in $x=-3$, you get
$$
\sqrt{|-3|} = \sqrt{3} \neq \sqrt{-3}
$$

Comment: @AnkitPandey Which value do you take for $x$ when you reach a point of calculation where you have to calculate $\sqrt{-3}$?

Comment: @Ankit Sorry I didn't see the modulus sign in the title of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root is only defined for non-negative real values.

However, since you are looking at the function $\sqrt{|x|}$, and the value $|x|$ is always non-negative, that shouldn't cause too much of a problem.

When plotting the function, you might want to remember that if a function is even, then its graph is symmetric across the *y* axis. So you can only draw the plot for $x>0$, then mirror it over the *y* axis to get the full plot.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x| \ge 0$, the function $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ is defined for all $x$.

For $x <0$ we have $|x|=-x$, hence $f(x)=\sqrt{-x}.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for **non-negative** values of x (positive x **and** 0).  But aren't you asking about $\sqrt{|x|}$?  If $x= -4$ then $|x|= 4$ so $\sqrt{|x|}= 2$.